# Why isn't the background color of my iframe changing?

Tags: html, css, iframe, background-color

This bit of code is going to be loaded in an iframe on a different page of a website I'm wroking on. However, the CSS that should be changing the background of the page isn't working. Even when I load just this (as in not in an iframe) it has a white background. What gives? Any ideas?

```
<!--Developed, Written, and Implemented by Henry Edward Quinn IV in May of 2012 for the a Company-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>
<title>More Text about Equipment</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style>
<!--This little bit of CSS styling is just to guarantee consistency.-->
body {background-color:#ebf0f3;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<!--This page will be loaded into an iframe. Only what's in the body will be visible on whatever page this will ultimately be on.
Since we're just filling a text box, keep the content limited to a handful of <p> tags in order for things to stay simple.-->
<a href="PATH/equipment.txt" target="_parent">More Information</a>
<p>
We've got some equipment here that has such and such a purpose and is extremely useful in certain situations (like A, B, and C).
</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I believe it's because you have an HTML comment inside your  tags. If you removed the comment it should work. Or use

/* This little bit of CSS styling is just to guarantee consistency.*/.

Comment: Troy's answer says the comment itself is the issue. I got rid of the comments entirely and the background color finally changes. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 6):

The `<!-- comment -->` isn't valid in CSS that you have:

```
<!--This little bit of CSS styling is just to guarantee consistency.-->
```

Use `/* your comment */` instead:

```
<style>
/*This little bit of CSS styling is just to guarantee consistency.*/
body {
       background-color:#ebf0f3;
       font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
     }
</style>
```